# css: how to float element under another element which has a particular 2 column layout

Tags: html, css, sass

I have the following: https://codepen.io/truetaurus/pen/KejbPE

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="one">
      ONE this is the content
      <br/>
      ONE this is the content
      <br/>
      ONE this is the content
      <br/>
      ONE this is the content
      <br/>
    </div>
    <div class="two">
      TWO this is the content
      <br/>
      TWO this is the content
      <br/>
      TWO this is the content
      <br/>
      TWO this is the content
      <br/>
      TWO this is the content
      <br/>
      TWO this is the content
      <br/>
      TWO this is the content
      <br/>
      TWO this is the content
      <br/>
      TWO this is the content
      <br/>
      TWO this is the content
      <br/>
    </div>
  <div class="three">
    THREE this is the content
    <br/>
    THREE this is the content
    <br/>
    THREE this is the content
    <br/>
    THREE this is the content
    <br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want a 2 column layout with the right column taking whatever height it needs and with the content in the left separated in 2 elements as seen in my codepen.

I would like for the green element to go right under the red element instead of how it is where it begins at the end of the blue elements height and without changing the structure. How could I achieve this without changing the layout and without using css grid?

Answer (score 1):

Use floats on the other containers as well.

```
.container {
  width: 700px;
  margin: auto;
}
.one {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  width: 500px;
}
.two {
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  float:right;
  width: 200px;
}
.three {
  background-color: green;
  float:left;
  width: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you define a height limit for the container, you can use flexbox with the following settings (`wrap`, `order` etc.):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 700px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
}
.one {
  order: 1;
  background-color: red;
  width: 500px;
}
.two {
  order: 3;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 200px;
}
.three {
  order: 2;
  background-color: green;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="one">
      ONE this is the content
      <br/>
      ONE this is the content
      <br/>
      ONE this is the content
      <br/>
      ONE this is the content
      <br/>
    </div>
    <div class="two">
      TWO this is the content
      <br/>
      TWO this is the content
      <br/>
      TWO this is the content
      <br/>
      TWO this is the content
      <br/>
      TWO this is the content
      <br/>
      TWO this is the content
      <br/>
      TWO this is the content
      <br/>
      TWO this is the content
      <br/>
      TWO this is the content
      <br/>
      TWO this is the content
      <br/>
    </div>
  <div class="three">
    THREE this is the content
    <br/>
    THREE this is the content
    <br/>
    THREE this is the content
    <br/>
    THREE this is the content
    <br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

(switch to full screen display to see the result correctly dispayed)

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS grid:

```
  .container {
   width: 700px;
   display : grid;
   margin: auto;
   grid-template-columns: auto auto;
   grid-template-rows: auto auto ; 
   }
   .one {
   background-color: red;
   float: left;
   width: 500px;
    grid-row : 1/2;
   }
  .two {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 200px;
    grid-row: 1/3;
   float: right; 
   }
   .three {
    background-color: green;
    width: 500px;
    }
```